# I'm trying to create the effect Delay with NAudio

Tags: c#, audio, delay, naudio

I'm trying to create the effect Delay with NAudio in C#, but I can not do it.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You would create your own class implementing `ISampleProvider` to perform the effect in. Then, you would need a delay algorithm. A good place to start if you are new to coding audio effects would be to look at [MusicDSP](http://www.musicdsp.org/). These algorithms are typically in C, but can easily be ported to C#